# How to Transmit Internet within 2 LAN Card installed on one PC using Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: networking, server, internet, dhcp

I have 2 LAN Cards Connected in one PC using Ubuntu 16.04

Router (ISP) is connected to PC through one LAN Card using DHCP — 192.168.0.103, 255.255.255.0, 192.168.0.1

The other LAN Card is connected to a 24 Port Switch using Static IP — 10.1.1.1, 255.255.255.0, No Gateway

Now I just need to transmit the Internet through Ubuntu PC from one LAN to the other and my Switch shall be connected to other users using Static IP.

Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set up your PC for ip forwarding and NAT. You can find an easy HOWTO here:

[Quick-Tip: Linux NAT in Four Steps using iptables - by Frank Wiles](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html)

Make sure to configure gateway 10.1.1.1 for your static side.